# Deny login (from lockscreen) after X unsuccessful attempts in RHEL/Fedora

Tags: fedora, rhel, security

I'm trying to achieve denying login to an user from lockscreen after X unsuccessful attempts for X seconds, just like in Windows via Account Lockdown policies in secpol.msc. We are using RHEL 8.2.

I tried adding

```
auth        required      pam_faillock.so preauth silent audit deny=3 even_deny_root unlock_time=300 
auth        [default=die]  pam_faillock.so  authfail  audit  deny=3 even_deny_root unlock_time=300
```

and

```
account     required      pam_faillock.so
```

to both  `/etc/pam.d/system-auth` and  `/etc/pam.d/password-auth`

However, that did nothing. Attempts are logged and I can see them via faillock, however logging in is not prevented in any way.
Is there any easy way to achieve this in Linux? It's quite necessary for protecting locked but powered on encrypted computers IMO.

Thanks!

Comment: Please provide the `auth` section of `/etc/pam.d/system-auth` and `/etc/pam.d/password-auth` files, the order of lines matter.

Comment: @binarysta What order it should be?

Answer (score 0):

The order of lines matter, the result of `/etc/pam.d/system-auth` and `/etc/pam.d/password-auth` should be something like this

```
auth        required      pam_env.so
auth        required      pam_faillock.so preauth silent audit deny=3 unlock_time=300
auth        sufficient    pam_fprintd.so
auth        sufficient    pam_unix.so nullok try_first_pass
auth        [default=die]  pam_faillock.so  authfail  audit  deny=3  unlock_time=300
auth        requisite     pam_succeed_if.so uid >= 1000 quiet
auth        required      pam_deny.so
```

Comment: Thanks! Do I also need to add these lines? account     required      pam_faillock.so

Comment: @Martin excuse me, what do you mean?

Comment: Like I mentioned in the post, I'm also adding line: "account     required      pam_faillock.so" to both system-auth and password-auth. Is it required?

Comment: @Martin yes, for sure, that line should be added for `account`, it can be last line in account section.

Comment: does not works, it only returns me to userpicker after X attempts.

Comment: @Martin you can login after n failed attempts?